# Split Excel Cell by last Delimiter

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I need to split a cell by the first delimter (reading right to left) so that I can put that value in another cell.

For Example, my data in cell A1 could look like:

```
"something - more something - a lot more of something - (this is the text I need)"
```

Cell B1 needs the value "(this is the text I need)"

so far what I have is:

```
=RIGHT(a1,LEN(FIND(RIGHT("-"),a1)))
```

but this seems to only return the last char: ")".

Comment: Do you know how many delimiters there might be? Or could there be any number?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need this formula:

```
=MID(A1,FIND("~~~~~",SUBSTITUTE(A1,"-","~~~~~",LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"-",""))))+1,LEN(A1))
```

Breakdown:

```
LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"-",""))
```

Counts the number of times "-" occurs within the cell,

```
SUBSTITUTE(A1,"-","~~~~~",LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"-","")))
```

Then replaces the last occurrence of "-" with "~~~~~". If "~~~~~" has the possibility of occurring normally in your input, use a different value here.

```
FIND("~~~~~",SUBSTITUTE(A1,"-","~~~~~",LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"-",""))))+1
```

Finds the position of the "~~~~~" that we just created, and adds one so we start just after it. And then finally, the full formula uses that position and `MID()` to extract the desired text.

Comment: thank you! I did end up finding the answer I needed at [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6133287/extract-the-last-substring-from-a-cell), but your explanation really helps to understand how its working.

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/q/18617349/5108803.

Comment: @Just_Some_Guy I knew I'd seen this before on here, but search didn't come up with anything. Of course, it was on SO!

Answer (score 15):

Both of the above would work, but here's something a little more digestible:

```
=TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"-",REPT(" ",LEN(A1))),LEN(A1)))
```

Comment: This works. It will be more helpful if you explain it.

Comment: @David: This is very well thought.

Comment: Like your result, it's best to interpret this right to left. Each instance of the '-' separater is replaced with spaces equal in number to the entire original cell, while preserving everything to the right of the final '-' seperator. This means you end up with a stack of leading spaces at the beginning of your final data element, which can then be trimmed off.

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try:

```
=TRIM(IF(ISERROR(FIND("-",A1)),"",MID(A1,FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(A1,"-",CHAR(1),LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"-",""))))+1,255)))
```

[image]

Comment: This works. It will be more helpful if you explain it.