# Split Excel Cell by last Delimiter and get Text to left

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I need to split a cell by the first delimter (reading right to left) so that I can put that value in another cell.

For Example, my data in cell A1 could look like:

```
"something - more something - a lot more of something - (this is the text I need)"
```

also note; there could be dashes else where as follows:

```
"something - more -something - a lot more of something - (this is the text I need)"
```

Cell B1 needs the value

```
"something - more something - a lot more of something "
```

or

```
 "something - more -something - a lot more of something
```

in the case of the seccond example

I asked the opposite of this question here: [Split Excel Cell by last Delimiter](https://superuser.com/questions/986084/split-excel-cell-by-last-delimiter) (this question is not the same as the question that I am asking) which gave me the following formula:

```
=MID(A1,FIND("~~~~~",SUBSTITUTE(A1,"-","~~~~~",LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"-",""))))+1,LEN(A1))
```

now I need to do the opposite of this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Split Excel Cell by last Delimiter](http://superuser.com/questions/986084/split-excel-cell-by-last-delimiter)

Comment: While I could have figured out what I needed to do from my previous question, the questions are not the same and I'm trying to accomplish 2 different task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the answer he gives a good breakdown of how the function is built and it would be easy to get the left side.

From the other answer:

```
FIND("~~~~~",SUBSTITUTE(A1,"-","~~~~~",LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"-",""))))+1
```

**Finds the position of the "~~~~~" that we just created, and adds one so we start just after it. And then finally, the full formula uses that position and `MID()` to extract the desired text.**

So you now have the position of the last -,  add in a left function and you have your function

```
Left(A1,FIND("~~~~~",SUBSTITUTE(A1,"-","~~~~~",LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"-",""))))
```