# Combining first two letters from first name and first two letters from last name

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013

I have a spreadsheet of usernames.

The first and last names are in the same cell of column `A`.

Is there a formula that will concatenate the first two letters of the first name (first word) and the first two letters of the last name (second word)?

For example `John Doe`, should become `JoDo`.

I tried

```
=LEFT(A1)&MID(A1,IFERROR(FIND(" ",A1),LEN(A1))+1,IFERROR(FIND(" ",SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","",1)),LEN(A1))-IFERROR(FIND(" ",A1),LEN(A1)))
```

but this gives me `JoDoe` as the result.

Comment: Essential reading: [Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/)

Comment: Do any of the answers do the trick? (If so, can you please flag it as The Answer by clicking the check mark left of the post.)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes; assuming each person only has a First and Last name, and this is always separated by a space you can use the below:

```
=LEFT(A1,2)&MID(A1,SEARCH(" ",A1)+1,2)
```

I could only base this answer on those assumptions as it is all you provided.

Or if you want a space to still be included:

```
=LEFT(A1,2)&" "&MID(A1,SEARCH(" ",A1)+1,2)
```

Comment: @prweq no probs, accept it as correct if it works for you

Comment: Simplest and easiest to understand solution. (Well, except for using `FIND()` instead of `SEARCH()`;-) ) Since you are assuming there is always a space separator, your second formula can be simplified to `=LEFT(A1,2)&MID(A1,SEARCH(" ",A1),3)`

Comment: @PeterH,, your formula have shortfall in case the Cell has First, Middle & Last Name it pull from First & Middle not from Last,,,  as # Bruce's Formula does only from First & Last Name ☺

Comment: @RajeshS I know. That's why my answer starts with `assuming each person only has a First and Last name`

Comment: [Falsehoods programmers believe about names](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/) ; not that it would make sense to handle all those cases from the get-go if your software hasn't an international reach

Comment: I suggest `TRIM(LEFT(A1,2))` just in case their first name only has one letter, but it may be easy enough to check for those special cases manually as well.

Comment: @EngineerToast That's a great modification provided the result is allowed to be less than four characters. See [my answer](//superuser.com/a/1382384) for a suggestion if the requirements are to always have four characters and that spaces are not allowed. An alternative custom modification would be `LEFT(TRIM(LEFT(A1,2))&single_char,2)`

Comment: @Aaron even if it will not have international reach many foreigners live in USA (assuming you are there) and many of them have multiple names.

Answer (score 11):

And to round things out, here's a solution that will return the first two characters of the first name, and the first two characters of the last name, *but* also accounts for middle names.

```
=LEFT(A1,2)&LEFT(MID(A1,FIND("~~~~~",SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","~~~~~",LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",""))))+1,LEN(A1)),2)
```

[image]

<sub>Thanks to [@Kyle for the main part of the formula](https://superuser.com/a/986091/529100)</sub>

Comment: You beat me to it ;-) (It was well past midnight and I need to sleep - was planning on adding this to my answer afterwards.) A slight improvement to your formula would be to use a single `~` instead of four. If you are concerned that a Tilda might be used as part of a name (!) or, more likely, been accidentally typed, just use a character that doesn't appear on any keyboard. I prefer to use `§`. `¶` is another good one.

Comment: @BruceWayne ,, your Formula is more competent,,, since it's accessing only Firts & Last name ignores Middle name ,,, Up voted ☺

Comment: @RajeshS What about people with [Spanish names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spanish_naming_customs), such as former F1 driver [Fernando Alonso Díaz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fernando_Alonso) who has 1 forename, 2 surnames, and no middle names?  (Or even King Felipe Juan Pablo **Alfonso de Todos los Santos de Borbón y de Grecia**?)

Comment: @Chronocidal now we're going down the rabbit hole of [what programmers believe about names](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/)

Comment: @robinCTS - Good call! I got the formula from another answer (edited in), and didn't really dig too much deeper.  Thanks for the tips!

Comment: @Chronocidal,, the OP's demand was to Access First & Last name and #BruceWayne's Formula is accessing both First & Last. What I've pointed to #Peter that his and other Formula will not access if 1st Middle & Last Name are in the Cell. If you need I can suggest you Function could access and return desire number of characters from all 3, 1st 2nd & Last name. ☺

Answer (score 9):

This is another way...

[image: Screenshot of worksheet]

- A - Name
- B - `=CONCATENATE(LEFT(A1,2),LEFT(RIGHT(A1,(LEN(A1)-FIND(" ",A1))),2))`

Comment: You could go even further and remove all those extra columns by merging them `=CONCATENATE(LEFT(A1,2),LEFT(RIGHT(A1,(LEN(A1)-FIND(" ",A1))),2))`

Comment: Yeah, I did that a few moments after!

Comment: yeah I noticed you edited the answer, Nice Answer !

Answer (score 5):

First off, I'd like to say that [PeterH's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1382309) is the simplest and easiest to understand. (Although my preference is to use `FIND()` instead of `SEARCH()` - typing two less characters helps in avoiding RSI ;-) )

An alternative answer that neither uses `MID()`, `LEFT()` nor `RIGHT()`, but instead uses `REPLACE()` to remove the unwanted parts of the name is as follows:

```dart
=REPLACE(REPLACE(A1,FIND(" ",A1)+3,LEN(A1),""),3,FIND(" ",A1)-2,"")
```

**Explanation:**

The inner `REPLACE(A1, FIND(" ",A1)+3, LEN(A1), "")` removes the characters from the third character of the last name onward, whilst the outer `REPLACE(inner_replace, 3, FIND(" ",A1)-2, "")` removes the characters from the third character of the first name up to and including the space.

---

**Addendum 1:**

The above formula can also be adapted to allow for a single middle name:

```dart
=REPLACE(REPLACE(A1,IFERROR(FIND(" ",A1,FIND(" ",A1)+1),FIND(" ",A1))+3,LEN(A1),""),3,IFERROR(FIND(" ",A1,FIND(" ",A1)+1),FIND(" ",A1))-2,"")
```

by replacing `FIND(" ",A1)` with `IFERROR(FIND(" ",A1,FIND(" ",A1)+1), FIND(" ",A1))`.

`FIND(" ", A1, FIND(" ",A1)+1)` finds the second space (by starting the search for the space after the first space) or errors otherwise.
`IFERROR(find_second_space, FIND(" ",A1))` finds the first space if there is no second space.

This (long-winded) version allows for any number of middle names:

```dart
=REPLACE(REPLACE(A1,FIND("§",SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","§",LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",""))))+3,LEN(A1),""),3,FIND("§",SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","§",LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",""))))-2,"")
```

In this case `FIND(" ",A1)` is replaced with `FIND("§", SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","§",LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",""))))`.

`LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",""))` counts the number of spaces.
`SUBSTITUTE(A1, " ", "§", count_of_spaces)` replaces the last space with `§`.
`FIND("§", last_space_replaced_string)` finds the first `§` which is the same as finding the last space.

(The `§` could, of course, be replaced with any character guaranteed not to exist in the full name string. A more general, safer alternative would be to use `CHAR(1)`. )

<s>Note that, of course, [BruceWayne's answer](//superuser.com/a/1382389) is the simplest and easiest to understand solution that allows for any number of middle names.</s> Well it was. Until I posted my [other answer](//superuser.com/a/1382847), that is ;-)

---

**Addendum 2:**

All of the solutions can be adapted to cater for the case of a single name only (if there's a requirement for a four character result) by wrapping them within an `IFERROR()` function like so:

`=IFERROR(solution, alternate_formula)`

Note that the above is a general case formula, and it might be possible to make a more efficient modification to a specific solution. For example, if the requirement in the case of a single name is to join the first two letters with the last two letters, [PeterH's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1382309) can be more efficiently adapted in this way:

```dart
=LEFT(A1,2)&MID(A1,IFERROR(SEARCH(" ",A1)+1,LEN(A1)-1),2)
```

To allow for the case of a single letter first name or an initial (assuming a space or dot is not acceptable as the second character) the following can be used with any solution:

`=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(solution, " ", single_char), ".", single_char))`

Note that the single character can be either hard-coded or calculated from the name. (Or use `""` to remove the space or dot.)

Finally, if you ***really*** need to cater for the case where the full name is a single character only(!), just wrap the single-name-only formula with *another* `IFERROR()`. (Assuming, of course, that the alternate formula doesn't take care of that special case.)

---

**Addendum 3:**

Finally, finally (no, really<sup>*</sup> ;-) ) to cater for multiple consecutive and/or leading/trailing spaces, use `TRIM(A1)` instead of `A1`.

<sup>* I'll leave the case for a single letter last name, like Mr T, as an exercise for the reader.</sup>

> Hint: `=solution &IF(MID(A1,LEN(A1)-1,1)=" ", single_char, "")`

Comment: As always your answers look like they are from an advanced user guide of Excel !    This would be the top voted answer had you posted it earlier !

Comment: @PeterH Thanks for the complement. I only stumbled across the question once it hit the Hot Network Questions list, so I was a bit late to the party ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Based on [this answer](//superuser.com/a/986097), here's an elegant solution which works with any number of middle names:

```dart
=LEFT(A1,2)&LEFT(TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",REPT(" ",LEN(A1))),LEN(A1))),2)
```

**Explanation:**

`SUBSTITUTE(A1, " ", REPT(" ",LEN(A1)))` replaces the inter-word space(s) with spaces equal in number to the length of the entire string. Using the string length rather than an arbitrarily large number guarantees the formula works for any length string and means it does so efficiently.

`RIGHT(space_expanded_string, LEN(A1))` extracts the rightmost word prepended by a bunch of spaces.<sup>*</sup>

`TRIM(space_prepended_rightmost_word)` extracts the rightmost word.

`LEFT(rightmost_word, 2)` extracts the first two characters of the rightmost word (last name).

<sup>*Caveat: If it's possible for a username to contain trailing spaces, you need to replace the first argument of `SUBSTITUTE()`, i.e. `A1`, with `TRIM(A1)`. Leading spaces and multiple consecutive spaces between words are handled correctly just with `A1`.</sup>

---

#### Fixing Your Attempt

Taking a closer look at your attempted solution, it looks like you were very close to a working formula to concatenate the first two letters of the first word (i.e. the first name) and the first two letters of the ***second*** word if it existed.

Note that if a username were to contain middle names, the corrected formula would incorrectly grab the first two letters from the first middle name instead of from the last name (assuming your intent is indeed to extract them from the last name).

Also, if all the usernames consist only of either a first name, or a first name and a last name, then the formula is needlessly complicated and can be simplified.

To see how the formula works and so fix it, it is easier if it is prettified, like so:

```dart
=
LEFT(A1,2) &
MID(
  A1,
  IFERROR(FIND(" ",A1), LEN(A1)) + 1,
  IFERROR(
    FIND(" ", SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","",1)),
    LEN(A1)
  )
  - IFERROR(FIND(" ",A1), LEN(A1))
)
```

To understand how it works, first look at what happens when `A1` contains no spaces (i.e. it contains a single name only). All the `IFERROR()` functions evaluate to their second arguments since `FIND()` returns a `#VALUE!` error if the search string is not found in the target string:

```dart
=
LEFT(A1,2) &
MID(
  A1,
  LEN(A1) + 1,
  LEN(A1)
  -LEN(A1)
)
```

The third argument of `MID()` evaluates to zero, so the function outputs `""` and the formula result is the first two characters of the single name.

Now look at when there are exactly two names (i.e there is exactly one space). The first and third `IFERROR()` functions evaluate to their first arguments but the second one evaluates to its second argument since `FIND(" ", SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","",1))` is attempting to find another space after removing the first, and only, one:

```dart
=
LEFT(A1,2) &
MID(
  A1,
  FIND(" ",A1) + 1,
  LEN(A1)
  - FIND(" ",A1)
)
```

Clearly, `MID()` returns the second word (i.e. the last name) in its entirety, and the formula result is the first two characters of the first name followed by *all* the characters of the last name.

For completeness sake, we'll also look at the case where there are at least three names, although it should be fairly obvious now how to fix the formula. This time, all the `IFERROR()` functions evaluate to their first arguments:

```dart
=
LEFT(A1,2) &
MID(
  A1,
  FIND(" ",A1) + 1,
  FIND(" ", SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","",1))
  - FIND(" ",A1)
)
```

It is slightly less clear than it was in the previous case, but `MID()` returns exactly the entire *second* word (i.e. first middle name). Thus, the formula result is the first two characters of the first name followed by all the characters of the first middle name.

Obviously, the fix is to use `LEFT()` to get the first two characters of the `MID()` output:

```dart
=
LEFT(A1,2) &
LEFT(
  MID(
    A1,
    IFERROR(FIND(" ",A1), LEN(A1)) + 1,
    IFERROR(
      FIND(" ", SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","",1)),
      LEN(A1)
    )
    - IFERROR(FIND(" ",A1), LEN(A1))
  ),
  2
)
```

The simplification I mentioned above is to replace `LEFT(MID(…,…,…), 2)` with `MID(…,…,2)`:

```dart
=
LEFT(A1,2) &
MID(
  A1,
  IFERROR(FIND(" ",A1), LEN(A1)) + 1,
  2
)
```

or on one line:

```dart
=LEFT(A1,2)&MID(A1,IFERROR(FIND(" ",A1),LEN(A1))+1,2)
```

This is essentially [PeterH's solution](//superuser.com/a/1382309) modified to also work with single names (in which case, the result is just the first two characters of the name).

**Note:** The prettified formulas actually work if entered.